# Tab Issue bootstrap

Tags: jquery

I am working with bootstrap tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <h4>Horizontal description lists will truncate terms that are too.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
        <p>narrower viewports, they will change to the default stacked layout.
        <a href="#" id="read">Read Reviews</a>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a id `read`. I want to open the home tab on click of this id and want to active the home tab.

Comment: Have you tried something like `<a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" id="read">Read Reviews</a>`?

Comment: it works but you will have to add some JS, change classes on active tabs

Comment: your code is steel working in bootstrap tabs...

Comment: guys code is working...   I want to active the home tab  and its tab-content container at same time on click of read id and again when i go from home tab to settings tab the setting tab should open with active state.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the below jquery on your page.

```
$('#read').click(function() {
    $('li a[href="#home"]').trigger('click');
});
```